# Supremum norm on the space is not differentiable.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential

Prove the supremum norm on the space $C[0,1]$ is not differentiable at any element $x$ for which there are two point $t$ in $[0,1]$ where $|x(t)|=\|x\|$.

My attemp: Suppose that $f:C[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, is differentiable for any point $[0,1]$. If we have two point $t_1,t_2\in[0,1]$ where $|x(t)|=\|x\|$, then the function $F(t)=f(v+tu)$ will be differentiable on $t=0$ for any element $v\in C[0,1]$.But know I don't see how take a contradiction for the function $f$, and therefore show that is not differentiable.

Comment: You have not used the given assumption. Look for special $u$ that takes advantage of having two points

Comment: I don't see how to choose the right $u$ for the problem

Comment: Bigger hint... Show that $f(x,y) := \max(|x|,|y|)$ is not differentiable when $|x|=|y|$

Comment: @CalvinKhor When $|x|=|y|$, then $f(x,y)=\frac{|x|+|y|+||x|-|y||}{2}=|x|$ which is not differentiable. Now, is it possible to extend this result to a finite number of points $t_i\in [0,1]$?? And how can conclude the original problem, 'cause the supremum norm is different from the max or not?

Comment: your proof doesn’t work because |x| **is** differentiable at $x\neq0$, but $f$ is not when $|x|=|y|>0$. And if you don’t prove from first principles it’s not easy to see the relationship. You should in particular prove that $f$ has a ‘bad direction $v$’ so that for $u=(x,y)$,  $f(u+tv)$ does….what?